# Using threeparttable with tabu

Tags: tables, tabu, threeparttable, tablenotes

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Problematic table}
\label{tab:lf_mikrofone}
\begin{tabu} {l l}
  Heading 1 & Heading 2 \\
  \midrule
  a\tnote{1} & b\tnote{2} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\begin{tablenotes}
  \item [1] qwerty
  \item [2] asdf
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This produces the expected output, but with an error:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tabu}
```

[image: Expected output]

If I change `\begin{tabu}` to `\begin{tabular}`, it works, but I would prefer `tabu`.

Exchanging `\usepackage{threeparttable}` for `\usepackage{threeparttablex}` makes no difference.

Can `threeparttable` and `tabu` be used together without errors?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The other question is about something totally different. The only commonality, is that the question uses the same packages.